# Redraw screen in update function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to redraw screen in update function

I will change some data and show it to screen and give delay 1000 milliseconds before next work.

```
void Update()
{
    ... // ChangeData
    // I want to redraw screen to apply changed data
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);    // delay 1000 milliseconds
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to force redraw screen in update method?

if it is impossible, how do I redraw screen before sleep

Comment: Why would you want to sleep the main thread for a second? This will freeze the app for that time, allowing nothing to happen, no drawing, no user input, nothing.

Comment: thanks for answer.  how do i sleep this logic? without freeze app

Comment: you probably want to use a coroutine

Comment: @user2523112 It is a bit unclear what you are trying to do. Can you edit your question and add more detail?